# Unknown user permission: UseMySearch

Tags: community, deployment, administration

Why am i getting this error while deploying my profiles into another sandbox. Please let me know hwo to solve this. i have tried verifying my components in the change set and everything looks fine

Comment: There must be some `<userPermissions>` in you profiles with name `UseMySearch`. Remove it and then try again.

Comment: Well, there is no user permission like that mentioned in the profile. if you are suggesting to change the XML data in the profile then I am doing through changeset so I cant do that

Comment: Santosh:Check out Setup > Einstein > Einstein Search > Search settings. This might be turned on in source but not in destination Org.

Comment: Thanks @Sridhar I completely forgot the einstein settings. yes i did enable this and yes this is what has been causing the issue as the destination org was not enabled